# How do I SSH to a Ubuntu Udroid XU4 device in this home network setup?

Tags: networking, server, ssh

My home network works like so:

All PCs in the house connect to -> home router

Then I have a shed up the garden which has its own router, which connects to the home router (via ethernet running underground up the garden). This shed router has a bunch of smart devices connected to it, and my devices when I'm up there.

I guess the shed router is more of a WAP than a router, as its not facing the internet directly, but rather sending traffic to the home router, which is connected to my ISP.

My question is, how do I configure this setup to allow me to SSH to the Ubuntu device in the shed, if my PC is connected to the home router, and the Ubuntu device is connected to the shed router, with both routers being connected via ethernet? I would've thought if I enabled SSH on the device, I could SSH directly. But I'm receiving nothing even when I try ping the device.

Any tips/guidance?

Comment: Check your router settings for allowing/disallowing connection between devices.

Comment: Make sure all devices you wish to have communication between are in the same subnet, e.g 192.168.x.y/24

Comment: Communicating across a router means you need to set up Port Forwarding (or VPN or DMZ) on that router. Alternately, look up how to use the shed router as a mere switch so everything is on the same LAN. A common networking question, but not really an Ubuntu-related question.